# How to check whether input only consists of 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make binary to decimal converter.

I want to cut input to 8 digits and allow only 0s and 1s with JavaScript functions.

The first test works, but I did not succeed yet in detecting inputs that have some other character than only 0s and 1s. How can I achieve that?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
function bin2dec() {
  var bin = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (bin.length > 8) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "8 digits";
  } else if (bin > 2) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "Enter binary value";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(bin, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you want to test with `bin > 2`? And what exactly is your question? (A question would have a question mark...)

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: I've copied broken code, I want to limit input value to only 0s and 1s,  I tried html input pattern, but no success.

Comment: I want to make function which meets this conditions:

- User can enter up to 8 binary digits in one input field
 
- User must be notified if anything other than a 0 or 1 was entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing `bin > 2` is not helpful. You could use a regular expression to check if the input contains any characters other than `0` and `1`.

```
if(/[^01]/.test(bin)){
   //not binary
}
```

```js
function bin2dec() {
  var bin = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  if (bin.length > 8) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "8 digits";
  } else if (/[^01]/.test(bin)) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "Enter binary value";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = parseInt(bin, 2);
  }
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=>bin2dec());
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button>Convert</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="alert" style="color: red;"></p>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've looking for, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @BloodOverdrive Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your question is about fixing this part:

```
else if (bin > 2) {
```

This condition would be true for the following inputs (remember the input is a string):

```
"30000000"
"98765432"
```

which is indeed what you want,... but it would not be true for all of the following, while it should:

```
"20000000"
"12345678"
"09999999"
```

To check that a string only consists of "0" or "1" you could use a regular expression:

```
if (/[^01]/.test(bin)) {
```

This `[^01]` means "a character that is neither '0' nor '1'". The `test` method will return true when a match is found, i.e. if there is such a character in `bin` that is not "0" nor "1".

Answer (score 1):

`bin > 2` only checks if the input is a decimal number and if it's less than 2. I don't think that's what you want. Try something like this:

```js
function bin2dec() {
  var bin = document.getElementById("input").value,
      num;
  if (bin.length > 8) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "8 digits";
  } else if (isNaN(num = parseInt(bin, 2))) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "Enter binary value";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = num;
  }
}
```

Explanation: `isNaN(num = parseInt(bin, 2))` assigns the parsed value to `num` and if it's invalid (`NaN`), says `"Enter binary value"`, otherwise continues to the `else` statement.